# CKAN Max Upload Size

Tags: python, tomcat, ckan

I'm trying to increase the maximum upload size into CKAN.

So far I have changed `development.ini` to read `ckan.max_resource_size = 1024` but that didn't help. I also added `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 104857600`
 to `datapusher_settings.py` but that didn't help either.

According to [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216804/ckan-upload-to-datastore-failed-resource-too-large-to-download) post I need to change something inside DataPusher. However that post is over two years old, so I want to check if that information is still correct?

Also, this [commit](https://github.com/ckan/datapusher/commit/013c19e1143bf68d54fe35804a092eabb1af2249) from August 2015 says that the hard coded limit of 10mb has been removed.

I'm running Tomcat, not Jetty. So the issue of [Jetty limiting upload sizes](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-form-size.html) isn't applicable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer here: [Does CKAN have a limit size of data to upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408049/does-ckan-have-a-limit-size-of-data-to-upload)

---

#### Process

Edited my `production.ini` file (location `etc/ckan/default`) and changed `# ckan.max_resource_size = 10` to `ckan.max_resource_size = 100`.

The changes I previous made to other files ([see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42974771/2878626)) may have also contributed to this solution, although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: If your site is served behind Nginx (it probably is) you also need to add the following line to the Nginx config file: `client_max_body_size 100M;` (eg https://github.com/ckan/ckan-packaging/blob/master/common/etc/nginx/sites-available/ckan#L5)